# how to make smooth grayscale on hover using CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions, grayscale

I have logo in my website, it is grayscaled on hover i want it to be colored smoothly. it is working but not smoothly. i am using CSS transition.

This is my code

```
<img alt="TT ltd logo" src="./img/tt-logo.png" class="tt-logo" />

   <style>
    img.tt-logo {
      filter: grayscale(1);
      transition: grayscale 0.5s;
    }

    img.tt-logo:hover {
      filter: grayscale(0);
    }
   </style>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try do it this way:

```
 img.tt-logo {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
   -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
   filter: grayscale(100%);
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
 }

 img.tt-logo:hover {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
   -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
   filter: grayscale(0%);
 }
```

and every image has its own `alt`, you can use it without using `img.class`:

```
 img[alt="TT ltd logo"] {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
   -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
   filter: grayscale(100%);
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
 }

 img[alt="TT ltd logo"]:hover {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
   -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
   filter: grayscale(0%);
 }
```

in this case `class` is extra

Comment: thank you :) it works but i am still confused that why all works but not grayscale ??

Comment: You need to animate the property. the property in this case is filter (or -webkit-filter). Not graycase, that is the value of the property

Comment: @vals Thank you very much I got it :)

Comment: `-moz-filter` does not exist. You can safely remove it as Firefox uses `-filter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Answer (score 10):

Animating a filter takes a lot of computation and might hurt performance in some browsers.

You can get better performance by animating the `opacity` of a grayscale image to reveal a full-color image beneath it.

[Here's an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/bt0fvqwm/)

Comment: i did not get you can you please show some example ?

Answer (score 5):

With the current state of browsers, you could go for the example below, short and simple.
Modern browsers nowadays support the grayscale CSS attribute and if you're only transitioning one attribute, best reference one attribute instead of all attributes.

```
img {
    grayscale: 1;
    transition: filter .23s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
    grayscale: 0;
}
```

Sources:

- [Animatable CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)
- [grayscale attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/grayscale())
- [Timings on transitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_processor_model)